# Question regarding basis and dimension of vector space of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $V_n$ be the vector space consisting of all polynomials of the form
>   $$f(x,y)=\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n a_{i,j}x^iy^j$$
>   where $a_{i,j}\in\mathbb{R}$.
>
> (a) State the dimension of $V$, and give a basis for $V$.
>
> (b) Let $U\leq V$ be the subspace of $V$ consisting of all $f\in V$ such that $f(x,x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Compute a basis for $U$, and determine the dimension of $U$.

Part (a) is relatively straightforward. The dimension is $(n+1)^2$. I am looking for assistance in how to express the basis. It is clear that a basis is composed of all monic polynomials of order $0$ to $n$ in $x$ and $y$. So, something along the lines of $\{1,x^i,y^j,x^iy^j:i,j=1,2,\cdots,n\}$, maybe?

For part (b), without the $a_{i,j}$ coefficients, $U$ would just be the trivial subspace, but I'm not sure otherwise.

Comment: Defining $x^0=1$, you could state your basis for (a) just as $\{x^iy^j\mid i,j\in\{0,\dots,n\}\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct about $(a)$.

For part $(b)$, note that $U$ is the kernel of the linear map $$V\to \Bbb R^{2n+1}:\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n a_{i,j}x^iy^j\mapsto \left(\sum_{i+j=N} a_{i,j}\right)_{N=0\ldots 2n+1}$$
This map is surjective, which gives you the dimension of $U$. For a basis, fix the value of $N$, set $a_{i,j}=0$ when $i+j\neq N$ and you are left essentially to compute a basis of the kernel of $$\Bbb R^{N+1}\to \Bbb R:(x_0,\ldots ,x_{N})\mapsto \sum_{i=0}^N x_i$$

Comment: Okay, I follow the dimension argument ($(n+1)^2-2n+1$, right?) but I'm not entirely sure how to use what you've given to compute the basis.

Comment: Actually, $(n+1)^2-(2n+1)$

Comment: You are correct about the dimension. To understand how to compute the basis, fix $N=0$: what basis elements correspond to that? Then $N=1$. When you understand the pattern, you can treat the case of arbitrary $N$.